# Photoshop script to ignore .ds_store

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

my skills with javascript are about 0, I only know some html and css. 
I hope someone can still help me solving this.

I am working in photoshop with a script that grabs pictures, does some magic and places them into a psd file as layers. As you might guess i haven't written the script but its needed for work.

The problem is, its grabbing the .ds_store files as well as the images, which results in an error warning.

this is the line that defines the source:

```
var taschenQuelle = Folder.selectDialog();
alert("Click OK to start processing.", "TEASER 2014");
var listeAllerTaschen = taschenQuelle.getFiles();
```

How can I specify that its ignoring the system files?

Best,

Lukas

Comment: btw, the script is working when i manually delete the .ds_store files

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore `.dotfile` and get files have 3-characters file extension by using following a snippet.

```
//@target "Photoshop"
var f = Folder.selectDialog("select");
alert(f.getFiles(function (file) {return /^[^.]+\.[^.]{3}$/i.test(file.name)}));
```

thank you

mg