# Photoshop script .DS_Store

Tags: photoshop-script

I'm using Photoshop script. I get files from folders. My problem is that when I get the files and place them in an array the array contains hidden files that are in the folder for example ".DS_Store". I can get around this by using:

```
if (folders[i] != "~/Downloads/start/.DS_Store"){}
```

But I would like to use something better as I sometimes look in lots of folders and don't know the "~/Downloads/start/" part.

I tried to use indexOf but Photoshop script does not allow indexOf. Does anybody know of a way to check if ".DS_Store" is in the string "~/Downloads/start/.DS_Store" that works in Photoshop script?

I see this answer but I don't know how to use it to test: [Photoshop script to ignore .ds_store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059681/photoshop-script-to-ignore-ds-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this problem, rather than explicitly trying to skip hidden files like .DS_Store, you can use the Folder Object's getFiles() method and pass an expression to build an array of file types you actually want to open.   A simple way to use this method is as follows:

```
// this expression will match strings that end with .jpg, .tif, or .psd and ignore the case
var fileTypes = new RegExp(/\.(jpg|tif|psd)$/i);

// declare our path
var myFolder = new Folder("~/Downloads/start/");

// create array of files utilizing the expression to filter file types
var myFiles = myFolder.getFiles(fileTypes);

// loop through all the files in our array and do something
for (i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
     var fileToOpen = myFiles[i];
     open(fileToOpen);
     // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking I used the Polyfill found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

> indexOf() was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as
>   such it may not be present in all browsers. You can work around this
>   by utilizing the following code at the beginning of your scripts. This
>   will allow you to use indexOf() when there is still no native support.
>   This algorithm matches the one specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition,
>   assuming TypeError and Math.abs() have their original values.